# Setting navigation bar text font in Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationbar, uifont

I am using a non-default font in my apps navigation bar, and this worked absolutely fine prior to Xcode 6.1. Now I get an error on the line of code where I am defining the font type and colour.

This is my code:

```
    var attributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(),NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 24)]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = attributes
```

What do I need to change to get this to work again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIFont(name:size:)` returns an optional, which cannot be used as the value.Change it to this:

```
var attributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(),NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 24)!]
```

By doing this you unwrap the `UIFont?` value to `NSFontAttributeName`. I believe you have to make sure the font is actually there to avoid crash.